# Convert to comment leads to 'Moderator action failed"

Tags: bug, comments, moderator-tools

Today as a moderator I tried to do something I've done umpteen times before, convert an answer that was really a reply from the OP that then became a brief discussion in comments, to a comment on the question, ticking the "move all comments on this question as well" box and I get [this page](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/admin/posts/103517/convert-to-comment) which I'd never seen before.  It just contains a brief message:

> #### Moderator action failed
>
> Only one additional @user can be notified; the post owner will always be notified

The answer in question is this one: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/103517/5538

Comment: Multiple mentions aren't allowed in comments. Could you edit out the `@`s of the answer and still convert it to a comment? (I have no idea if edited answers can be converted or not - I'm a mod on exactly 0 sites). Still needs to be fixed, but you can at least handle this case if you have a workaround

Comment: @Olivia having an edit history is irrelevant. :) That should work just fine.

Comment: No pings now, but no luck.

Comment: In this specific case, you're probably better off adding the additional information into the question rather than leaving it in the comments anyway. :D

Comment: Looks like they're all still there (unless there's some magic edit box for mods during merging)

Comment: Oh sheesh *in the question*.  Who does such a thing?!? Did not consider that.  I see an answer in the works.

Comment: Well, if the details are missing from the question, they should be added to the question so that an answer can be written based on all of the needed info - without relying on someone reading the comments. That's a best-practice we recommend for all of our sites. :D

Comment: Okay will do...usually I just like throwing the hammer around.  >_>

Comment: uhm. Did someone push an update on a friday? You shouldn't be pushing updates on fridays ;p

Answer (score 6):

The original poster of the question, a bone fide "New contributor", used an answer to reply to questions asked in comments.  This is pretty common.  What they had also done, which I just glanced at, was try to ping multiple other users in the question, like:

> @bob: Yeah the widget is defunct. @trace-E: I don't understand.
>   @themaster: Thanks for the tip!

When this gets converted to a comment it fails because of the multiple pings.  Removing the `@`s first solved the problem.

Comment: Wasn't it better to merge the answer to the Question to begin with then? Not sure if that is actually something that can be done at all...

Comment: Not automagically as far as I know.  We can merge *all* the questions tho :D

Comment: You can convert an answer by the OP to an edit (appending to the question) - the option is in the post mod menu

Comment: Right yeah I knew that <_<